# Why it shows "You are opening the application 'Xcode' for the first time?

Tags: macos, xcode, error

[image]

I am running XCode v.5.1 in my Mountain Lion, I don't know why, but I'm getting this message after a successful start of Mac computer. I was already using this version of XCode before and now suddenly it's showing me this message? What's wrong? It is something that Apple forgets its my first run?

Comment: Did you update xCode?

Comment: Yes, I'd updated it from XCode v.5.0 to v.5.1. And v.5.1 was already running (I can say, some couple of weeks)! Then sudden this message appearing.

Comment: Does it appear every time you close Xcode and subsequently reopen it? Or did it just occur this one time?

Comment: You could consider removing XCode and perform a new install using the AppStore. Please post the results afterwards. During the update something might have caused this issue. Please try this first.

Answer (score 2):

If you're not able to set the quarantine status on the app, then it will forever have that status and will prompt you. You can manually remove quarantine from the app with…

```
xattr -d com.apple.quarantine /Applications/Xcode.app
```